# Will the new ActionBar API be included in the Fragment backport?

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

With the blogpost yesterday regarding us getting a healthy dose of Fragments all the way back to 1.6, I was wondering, will the ActionBar APIs be included in this backport?

They **appear** to be somewhat linked together, from the API Docs at the least. However, I could see the Fragments being separate from the ActionBar, but not visa-versa.

Anybody have any news?

Thanks -- Selig

Comment: I sure hope so, but in the event they don't this question provides some solid examples of how to implement an ActionBar in 2.X: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900509/android-action-bar-like-twitter-sample

Comment: On a separate note, it will be possible to to use the ActionBar when running in 3.0, while remaining backwards compatible, by setting your `targetSdkVersion` appropriately. Action bar styling and theming can be done purely in XML and the `ActionBar` class methods can be invoked via reflection.

Comment: I have written an extension of the Android Compatibility Library which includes support for the action bar through a single API as well as a single theme. It supports Android 1.6 up through the current latest, 3.1. You can find more info at http://actionbarsherlock.com.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No it won't be included in the fragments library. The ActionBar is not tied to fragments at all.

Comment: Ah, that is a shame. Any chance you guys would backport it, because it has a rather nice API, better than the ActionBar librarys I've seen so far.

Comment: It is more challenging because it is more deeply tied into the framework -- I think making this available would require a fairly radical change to its current API.  (For example the framework's Menu APIs were extended to support the action bar.)  So in this case I think it probably makes more sense to create a new implementation, modeled after the one in Honeycomb.  This is very different from the  Fragment and Loader APIs, which were literally just a couple days to copy the entire HC implementation to a library that works on older platforms.

Comment: Ah, what lead me to beleive that they were tied together is the docs for the ActionBar state that the tabs are used to switch between fragments. Thanks for the reply. :)

Answer (score 9):

ActionBarSherlock at https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock is an Android library for implementing the action bar design pattern using the native ActionBar on 3.0+ and a third-party library on pre-3.0.

It uses one of the other ActionBar implementations on pre-3.0 devices, either:

GreenDroid at https://github.com/cyrilmottier/GreenDroid

or android-actionbar at https://github.com/johannilsson/android-actionbar

Answer (score 3):

No, it won't but here is official Android sample that will help you achieve [ActionBar from 1.6 to 4.x](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ActionBarCompat/index.html)

Comment: Which sample? I looked at the samples from v4 and v11 and did not see it.

Comment: @trgraglia, <path to SDK>/samples/android-16/ActionBarCompat