# How to implement the action bar in api levels less than 11?

Tags: android

I recently read about the action bar implementation in android in the dev site.But i found that it requires a minimum api level of 11.Can someone tell me whether it is possible to implement action bar in Api levels less than 11 such as 8 or 9.If yes how can i do this?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900509/android-action-bar-like-twitter-sample

Answer (score 17, accepted):

ActionBarSherlock at http://actionbarsherlock.com is an Android library for implementing the action bar design pattern using the native ActionBar on 3.0+ and a third-party library on pre-3.0.

There is now also ActionBarCompat - part of the Android Support Library: http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2013/08/actionbarcompat-and-io-2013-app-source.html

Comment: thanks ashton.Seems like I got what i wanted following your link.The compatability package would do the job it seems.
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/fragments-for-all.html

Comment: Thanks for the mention, @AshtonBRSC. @rogerstone The compat library does not include support for the action bar. The library of mine mentioned above has been recently updated to be based on the compatibility library and include an action bar implementation for API levels less than 11. You can check it out at http://actionbarsherlock.com. The GitHub repo is still the same as well.

Comment: i guess the question for now is what to use among those 3?

Comment: As I hinted by the order I placed the links in, I recommend trying ActionBarSherlock. It's the most comprehensive and as close to native as it can be on all versions of Android.

Comment: I uses this https://github.com/johannilsson/android-actionbar and it is very easy, i like.

Comment: Sorry but actionbarsherlock does not seem to work with API level 10. The requirements section says "Due to its use of the native action bar and its related classes on Ice Cream Sandwich, the library requires that both it and your project are compiled with Android 4.0 or newer"... Well, so any alternative for API level 10 ?

Comment: @ChristopheFondacci That just means it needs to be *compiled* with API version 14 or newer. It will still run on earlier versions.

Answer (score 2):

There are third-party implementations of the action bar available. See this library project at github: [android-actionbar](https://github.com/johannilsson/android-actionbar). The manifest says the minimum API level is 3, target API is 8.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a simplistic Actionbar solution you might want to give a look to [ActionBarCompat](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ActionBarCompat/index.html) from the Google Official examples

Comment: I tried this but the action bar is not displayed on the GB version. Doesn't that defeat the purpose of this package?

Comment: It should give you an actionbar but without an overflow. That's why is simplistic

Comment: I see. How do you get a handle on the action items though? I haven't found a way yet.

Comment: Justa as a regular menu does onOptionsItemSelected if you are inside a fragment remeber to do setHasOptionsMenu(true)