# How to override SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider

Tags: android

This is about Google map api. How do I override the class `SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider`. I want to use my own database for the search result, not the history of what you input in the input box.

Answer (score 0):

This is well explained in these two articles

- [Using search dialogs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html)
- [Adding custom suggestions](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-custom-suggestions.html)

Comment: The [source code is in the API demos](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SearchableDictionary/index.html). If you are not familiar, you should take some time to read the articles and understand the mechanics behind it.

Comment: I met a problem on it.The demos must work on Android Api 11,but my project is developed on Android API 7. What should I do?

Comment: Which api is requesting for minimum sdk 11?

Comment: `ActionBar` is only available for SDK 11 onwards, [see this if you are interested in implementing it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349170/how-to-implement-the-action-bar-in-api-levels-less-than-11)