# Android Crash while running AsyncTask on targetSdkVersion 8

Tags: android, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception, imageview

My app crashed when I set my `android:targetSdkVersion="8"` but when I set it to `android:targetSdkVersion="11"` everything goes fine. Please look at logcat, I really dont know whats wrong with my codes. It looks like any device using SDK below 11 will get this problem. My min sdk is 7. I might bump into alot trouble if I continue to deliver my app.

```
public class SingleMenuItemActivity  extends Activity {

    // XML node keys
static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
static final String KEY_ARTIST = "artist";  
static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumb_url";
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
String title;
String artist;
String image_url;
ImageView view;
Intent intent;
Context context;
ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.single_list_item);
        new loadSingleView().execute(); 




        view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.single_image);

    }

public class loadSingleView extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(
                    SingleMenuItemActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Connecting to Server ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // updating UI from Background Thread


            Intent in = getIntent();

            image_url = in.getStringExtra(KEY_THUMB_URL);
                        title = in.getStringExtra(KEY_TITLE);
            artist = in.getStringExtra(KEY_ARTIST);

            return null;

                    }
        @Override       
        protected void onPostExecute(String args) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products

            ImageLoader imgLoader = new ImageLoader(getApplicationContext());

            imgLoader.DisplayImage(image_url, view);

            TextView lblName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name_title);
            TextView lblCost = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name_artist);



            lblName.setText(title);
            lblCost.setText(artist);

            ActionBar ab = getActionBar();
            ab.setTitle(title);

            pDialog.dismiss();

        }


}
```

Logcat:

```
08-19 02:19:03.351: E/AndroidRuntime(22761): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-19 02:19:03.351: E/AndroidRuntime(22761): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-19 02:19:03.351: E/AndroidRuntime(22761):    at com.example.androidhive.SingleMenuItemActivity$loadSingleView.onPostExecute(SingleMenuItemActivity.java:88)
08-19 02:19:03.351: E/AndroidRuntime(22761):    at com.example.androidhive.SingleMenuItemActivity$loadSingleView.onPostExecute(SingleMenuItemActivity.java:1)
08-19 02:19:03.351: E/AndroidRuntime(22761):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
08-19 02:19:03.351: E/AndroidRuntime(22761):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
08-19 02:19:03.351: E/AndroidRuntime(22761):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)
08-19 02:19:03.351: E/AndroidRuntime(22761):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-19 02:19:03.351: E/AndroidRuntime(22761):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-19 02:19:03.351: E/AndroidRuntime(22761):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4512)
08-19 02:19:03.351: E/AndroidRuntime(22761):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-19 02:19:03.351: E/AndroidRuntime(22761):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-19 02:19:03.351: E/AndroidRuntime(22761):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:982)
08-19 02:19:03.351: E/AndroidRuntime(22761):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:749)
08-19 02:19:03.351: E/AndroidRuntime(22761):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Got it . Thanks everyone. I'll accept earliest answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SDK 8 does not have `ActionBar`. You will have to use something like the `ActionBarSherlock` library to have `ActionBar` support for SDK < Honeycomb.

Answer (score 2):

I think these code lines cause Exception in **API 8**,

```
 ActionBar ab = getActionBar();
 ab.setTitle(title);
```

Because, [ActionBar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) were added in **Android 3.0 (API level 11)**. From Android Docs..

For you subject concerns..

Please Look at these two SO Questions..

1. [ActionBar pre Honeycomb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646169/actionbar-pre-honeycomb)
2. [How to implement the action bar in api levels less than 11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349170/how-to-implement-the-action-bar-in-api-levels-less-than-11)

Comment: Also look at [Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html) IF its help you.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing which is line 88, the problem is probably here:

```
ab.setTitle(title);
```

ActionBar was added in API 11

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html