# Orientation change using Sherlocktabs in Gingerbread

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, android-fragmentactivity

Basically this is the problem I have with orientation concerning sherlocktabs.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_leavetab);


    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

    // Hide Actionbar Title
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    View homeIcon = findViewById(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ? android.R.id.home
            : R.id.abs__home);
    ((View) homeIcon.getParent()).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    // Create Actionbar Tabs
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    // Set Tab Icon and Titles
    Tab1 = actionBar.newTab().setText("New Leave");
    Tab2 = actionBar.newTab().setText("My Leaves");
    // Set Tab Listeners
    Tab1.setTabListener(new TabListener(leaveform));
    Tab2.setTabListener(new TabListener(leave));


    // Add tabs to actionbar
    actionBar.addTab(Tab2);
    actionBar.addTab(Tab1);
    // actionBar.addTab(Tab3);      
}
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("tabState", ActionBar.getSelectedTab());
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
            new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#FF8512")));
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.leave, menu);
    MenuItem menu1 = menu.findItem(R.id.reload_list);
    menu1.setTitle(name);
    return true;
}
```

The above fragment activity creates three two tabs - listfragment and a fragment. When I change the orientation of screen to landscape I get a fatal exception like below

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not
>   perform this action after onSaveInstanceState  at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1343)
>   at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1361)
>   at
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:595)
>   at
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:574)
>   at
>   com.actionbarsherlock.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.selectTab(ActionBarImpl.java:536)
>   at
>   com.actionbarsherlock.internal.app.ActionBarImpl$TabImpl.select(ActionBarImpl.java:912)
>   at
>   com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.ScrollingTabContainerView$TabClickListener.onClick(ScrollingTabContainerView.java:504)
>   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)  at
>   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)  at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)  at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

This works just fine in devices with api >11 but crashes in devices with api <11. I am quite new to fragments and thereby wondering about what the problem might be. Is is something concerning the saved state of activity?

Answer (score 0):

"Fragments require API Level 11 or greater"

From: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: That's why I am using actionbarSherlock which supports pre-3.0 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349170/how-to-implement-the-action-bar-in-api-levels-less-than-11

Answer (score 0):

For fragment, use `.commitAllowingStateLoss()` method instead of `.commit();`
Or try commenting out
`//super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);` and see if that helps