# Action bar like in Google docs and picassa tool apps

Tags: android, user-interface, android-actionbar

I see some kind of action bars in some pre-honeycomb apps. For example in Google docs and picassa tool apps. Some non-google apps have the same action bar too. For example twitter. This bars looks similar. Is there some control or widget?

Comment: see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900509/android-action-bar-like-twitter-sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Action Bar re-uses items from the Options menu and was introduced in the 3.0 SDK. You enable it in your app by following the instructions [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html).

For a "pre-honeycombe" app you will still need to build against the 3.0 SDK; increase the targetSdkVersion value in your manifest to "11" and set the minSdkVersion to the lowest Android version you are supporting. For example:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="11" />
```