# How to create Android custom titlebar

Tags: android, customization, titlebar

I try to build an application on Android.
And I'm new in Android.
But I don't know how to build a Title Bar like this.
So we can give the application name like Seesmic and Komutta with the tab button.
Can anyone help me to give me the answer or just a link for that tutorial?

Thank you.

https://lh6.ggpht.com/Hf6XKfa9K0B-CvlV6tD6qj2Yt8wJcyJ7wa8vE9BVkBbUDm0Y2pqOxgxVf7auQgXrh0gR

https://lh4.ggpht.com/rwceS5ZK1IZkHHCVixbaXlsHXwstpmIO888aMC4U0uD2oa54NiGvphcp_penGK9Q9WE

I'm sorry I can't upload the image, so I just can give the link for that image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called "Action Bar" you can get it nativly starting from [Android 3.0](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html)  or grab code to do it on earlier versions of android [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900509/android-action-bar-like-twitter-sample)

Answer (score 0):

android site has a demo you can check [CustomTitle](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/CustomTitle.html), and [how-to-create-custom-window-title-in-android](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-custom-window-title-in-android/)

Comment: Thank's for your suggestion, but it still appear the title when my application first started, but it's not to long. How can we solve thet problem?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new project and name your main activity "MyActivity"
2. Go to res - drawable and create a new xml file and call it "custom_title_background" and put the following code:

   ```
   <item android:top="20dp">
       <shape android:shape="rectangle">
           <gradient android:angle="90" android:endcolor="#9eacbf" android:startcolor="#8296af">
       </gradient></shape>
   </item>
   ```

This drawable will be used to set the background from custom_title_bar (from step 3) and to set the windowTitleBackgroundStyle from custom_title_style (from step 4)

1. Go to res-layout and create a new xml and name it "custom_title_bar". Here you will create a layout with a text view like in the following code:

   ```
   <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:textSize="16sp"
             android:textColor="@android:color/white"
             android:textStyle="bold"
             android:id="@+id/custom_title_text"
             android:layout_centerInParent="true"
             android:shadowColor="@android:color/black"
             android:shadowRadius="3"/>
   ```
2. Go to res - values and create a new xml file and call it custom_title_style. Here you will create a new theme by overriding the existing one. The name of the style "custom_title_theme" from below will be used into the manifest file to "activate" the new theme.

   40dp
           @drawable/custom_title_background
3. Now go to the AndroidManifest.xml file and put the new theme in the application tag.

?
1

1. And at this last step, you have to go to the MyActivity class and put the following code:

   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.view.Window;
   import android.widget.TextView;

   public class MyActivity extends Activity {

   ```
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       //this must be called BEFORE setContentView
       requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);

       setContentView(R.layout.main);

       //this must bew called AFTER setContentView
       getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.custom_title_bar);

       //set the title
       TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.custom_title_text);
       textView.setText("Custom Title");
   }
   ```

   }